# What is the Razor syntax for adding a C# condition in the script tag

Tags: razor, razor-pages

I have a script tag in my Razor cshtml file. I would like to conditionally add Javascript based on a property in my model.

Here is what I have done. Both attempts work. But is there a better way, e.g. what if my Javascript is more than a single line of code?

**Attempt 1**

```
@section scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    @if (Model.IsAdding)
    {
        @Html.Raw("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        ;
    }
</script>
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
@section scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       @(Model.IsAdding? "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);" : "")
    });
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<text></text>` tag

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            @if (Model.IsAdding)
            {
                <text>
                    // add your javascript code here
                    alert("test");
                </text>
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```